# Java Spring 3.0 MVC Annotation vs COC. Whats the preferred method in the Java community?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using Spring's MVC framework for an application I'm hosting on Google's App Engine. So far, my controllers are registered via the @Controller annotation; however, prior to getting into Spring, I evaluated ASP.net MVC 2 which requires no configuration and is based on convention. Is convention over configuration (COC) the current and preferred method in the Java community to implement MVC with Spring? Also, this may be a result of my limited knowledge so far, but I noticed that I could only instantiate my Controllers the required constructor injection if I use the COC method via the `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping`. For instance, the following controller bean config will fail if I use the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`.

```
<bean id="c" class="com.domain.TestController">
  <constructor-arg ref="service" />
</bean>
<bean id="service" class="com.domain.Service" />
```

My `com.domain.TestController` controller works fine if I use `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping`/COC but it results in an error when I use `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`/Annotations.

**To clarify**, I can get the constructor injection to work if I add the `@Autwired` annotation to the constructor, but if I do, I have to remove the `@RequestMapping` annotation or I will get an error stating that the controller is being mapped to the URL more than once. Some researching online indicates that the `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` is loading and mapping my controller to the URL even though I have 
`<context:annotation-config />` and `<context:component-scan base-package ... />` in my config file.

Honestly, I can overcome these issues. I really just want to know which method, annotation or COC, is the better investment.

Comment: when using the default annotation handlermapping, you have to set the scan base and also the `RequestMapping` on the controller method. Are you doing that??

Comment: yes. everything thing is works when i use default annotation handlermapping except the controlers that require constructor injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky question; it's a little subjective and really just up to your personal preference or your dev team's consensus.  I personally like annotations because I feel like it's more flexible.  If you have to follow conventions to get your framework to "automagically" do stuff, you are stuck with whatever convention the framework developers decided on (granted, it's usually not a *bad* convention, but you *are* stuck with it).  During my time of using Spring (2 years or so), it's always seemed like our team has started out using COC, only to realize later that our needs aren't really best served by the typical convention.  
I also feel like annotations improve the readability of your code.  When looking at an annotated class, I can understand what it does and how it does it without needing to reference the application context.

As for your second question (injecting beans into a controller), here's some code to show how I usually wire a controller.

web-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.web.controllers" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

TestController.java

```
package com.test.web.controllers

import com.test.dao.TestDAO;

@Controller
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myTestDAO")
    private TestDAO testDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome.htm*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelMap showWelcomePage() {
        ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
        model.addAttribute("products", testDAO.getOfferedProducts());
        return model;
    }
}
```

TestDAO would then have this class declaration:

```
@Repository("myTestDAO")
public class TestDAO {
```

I usually don't use constructor wiring because this is usually simpler, but if you need constructor wiring, I can post an example of that instead.